# If $X,Y,Z$ are independent random variables having identical density functions

Tags: statistics, random-variables, density-function

If $X,Y,Z$ are independent random variables having identical density functions $f(x) = e^{-x} $ , $0 < x < \infty$ , derive the joint probability density of the vector $(U,V,W)$ , where

\begin{align}
U &= X + Y \\
V &= X + Z \\
W &= Y + Z
\end{align}

I'm not sure on how to do this but, if were to find the joint probability density... I would do moment generate function for each $U,$ $V$ and $W$  and then multiple those.

Comment: If you _knew_ that $U,$ $V$ and $W$ were already independent, then you would be able to use the method you want, but they don't seem independent at first glance (and they aren't, look at my solution below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to use the change of variables theorem. Consider the random vector $(X,Y,Z)$ and notice that:
$$f_{(X,Y,Z)}(x,y,z) = e^{-(x+y+z)} \mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{R}_+^3}(x,y,z).$$
Define the transformation 
$$T:(x,y,z) \mapsto (x + y, x + z, y + z)$$ which is linear and possesses the inverse
$$S:(u,v,w) \mapsto \left(\dfrac{u+v-w}{2},\dfrac{u - v + w}{2}, \dfrac{-u+v+w}{2} \right).$$
By the change of variables theorem, the random vector $(U,V,W) = T(X,Y,Z)$ has density
$$f_{(U,V,W)}(u,v,w) = f_{(X,Y,Z)}(S(u,v,w)) |\det \mathbf{D}S(u,v,w)|.$$
Now, $\det \mathbf{D}S(u,v,w) = \det S = -\dfrac{1}{2},$ so
$\begin{align}
f_{(U,V,W)}(u,v,w) &=\dfrac{1}{2} f_{(X,Y,Z)}\left(\dfrac{u+v-w}{2},\dfrac{u - v + w}{2}, \dfrac{-u+v+w}{2} \right) \\
&= \dfrac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{u+v+w}{2}}  \mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{R}_+^3} \left(\dfrac{u+v-w}{2},\dfrac{u - v + w}{2}, \dfrac{-u+v+w}{2} \right) \\
&= \dfrac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{u+v+w}{2}}  \mathbf{1}_{\mathrm{G}}(u,v,w),
\end{align}$

where $\mathrm{G}$ is the set of $(u,v,w)$ such that the three relations $u + v \geq w,$ $u + w \geq v$ and $v + w \geq u$ hold. (Naturally, these three relations imply $u,v,w \geq 0$).